# How to push your codes/file to github via Rscript?

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

I am able to push the files via command prompt with the same code, it worked fine, but when I do the same via Rscript I get many errors:

My Rscript code:

```
shell(noquote(paste("cd C:/Users/XXX/Documents/github/t1 && git add .&& git commit -m",dQuote("4th commit"),"&&git push",sep = " ")))
```

I get the following error:

> shell(noquote(paste("cd C:/Users/XXX/Documents/github/t1 && git add .&& git commit -m",dQuote("4th commit"),"&&git push",sep = " ")))
>   error: pathspec 'commitâ€' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>   Warning messages:
>   1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c cd C:/Users/XXX/Documents/github/t1 && git add .&& git commit -m “4th commit” &&git push' had status 1 
>   2: In shell(noquote(paste("cd C:/Users/XXX/Documents/github/t1 && git add .&& git commit -m",  :
>     'cd C:/Users/XXX/Documents/github/t1 && git add .&& git commit -m “4th commit” &&git push' execution failed with error code 1

What am I doing wrong here? what is error code 1 & how to resolve this problem.

- I know I can do these things from git tab in R, but I want it to be a part of a function, so that we can automate.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a good process flow it would be better that you call git from a shell script. If it is important to both call your R scripts and git, you can gather both in a shell script (or have a master shell script, that calls for Rscript and git).

If you further on want to automate, you call for these script from crontab (if you are in linux environment) or a job scheduler.